# Azure DataFactory - diagnostics settings - activate logging to resource specific table

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics

I want to change diagnostics settings on my azure datafactory resource.

Actually, i'm logging into Azure Diagnostics table but i encounter a problem with max size (500 columns limit).

In my ARM template, i have added this :

```
"logAnalyticsDestinationType": "Dedicated"
```

But when i deploy this new template, my logging table stay the same -> Azure Diagnostics

What could be wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ARM template looks correct.  Just to make sure if you click Diagnostic settings is it correct?

Are you expecting the old records to be migrated to the new tables?  If so that would not happen.

You should see tables like this appear after 10-20 minutes as it's a schema on read so it needs to create the tables on the fly:

[image]

If you have waited and don't see the tables the 500 column "bug" that you are referring to might be impacting this as well. I am familiar with it and after working with MS on it, there is no quick and easy fix to this.

I would suggest creating a new workspace and send the logs there and the tables should be created. If you have any subsequent queries/dashboards they'd have to be updated to [query across workspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query).

In fact because of this limit MS recommends now have a [separate workspace per application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/resource-logs-collect-workspace)

Comment: my bad, 30~45 min later my modification was visible...


I did not expect it to be so long